# Excel : Columns by row value

Tags: excel, textjoin

Is there a method without using macro or script, to get this result?

```
Bus Line    L1  L2  L3  L4  Result
Stops                   
1               X       X   L2,L4
2                       X   L4
3           X       X       L1,L3
```

I need to concatenate COLUMN'S NAME for each "X" on rows.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Yeah. I was trying to use MATCH, INDEX or LOOKUP. For example =MATCH("X";B1:E3;0) dosn't find anything. Orizzontal lookup search the first row and then get the row you want in the same column but I want the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **F2** enter the array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:E2="X",$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array version of TEXTJOIN()

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:E2="x",$B$1:$E1,""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

You can also use helper columns. In H2 put:

```
=IF(B2="X","," &B$1,"")
```

Drag over 4 columns and down the length of the data.

Then in F2 put:

```
=MID(H2&I2&J2&K2,2,99)
```

[image]

The other option is a long formula that combines the two steps above:

```
=MID(IF(B2="X","," &B$1,"")&IF(C2="X","," &C$1,"")&IF(D2="X","," &D$1,"")&IF(E2="X","," &E$1,""),2,99)
```

Comment: I don't have textjoin. Its seems avaliable only in Excel 365

Comment: Then look at the duplicate, because you will need vba.

Comment: That return to my original question: without using macro or script. So the answer is "NO"

Comment: I guess you could use a bunch of helper cells.

Comment: @RetroMime to avoid vba, the options are above.  Otherwise vba is your only choice.

Comment: To resolve, Im using Google Sheet that has textjoin function. The Syntax is similar. Its only need to wrap the "IF" condition in ArrayFormula.